# Some http requests are not send encrypted by vpn! Why?

Tags: encryption, vpn, firefox, wireshark, browser-extensions

I subscribed to a VPN service recently, and installed wireshark to take a look at the traffic sent from my computer.

Practically all of it goes through UDP protocol, encrypted. But there are two HTTP requests that are sent through TCP, not encrypted. One of them comes from an Firefox extention that updates imageboard threads, and it's GET request has the thread's URL and cookies, so that's an issue. The other one is from jQuery and has the website it's from in "referer" and a session cookie. The source of these requests is the VPN's internal IP address, but still, they're sent unencrypted.

Is that normal firefox entensions and jQuery behaviour? Why can I see the data they sent through wirehsark? I thought literally everything would be sent encrypted by the VPN.

Comment: What service are you using? The configuration of the routing tables determine what goes through a VPN.

Comment: I'm using 'Private Internet access'. Perhaps I should contact their client support, then? Or is there something I can do?

Comment: Did you use Wireshark on the same computer or on a different computer? If the same computer it is possible you are just misinterpreting what you see, and the traffic doesn't actually leave the computer unencrypted.